# I'm not able to see the Line number in the SQL Server 2017 Express, even if Line Number checked correctly

Tags: ssms-2017

Here is the image of the option window with the Line Number Checked correctly

[image]

SQL Server 2017 Express Edition
Windows 10 64 bits
Following the below path
Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> Plain Text --> Line Number 
I tried multiple times shutting down the system, not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: More Information: I'm using SQL Server 2017 Express Edition,  Windows 10 64 bits, Following the path Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> Plain Text --> Line Number, I tried multiple times shutting down the system, not sure what I'm missing here. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are working with .sql files you will want to adjust the setting in this path Tools → Options → Text Editor → Transact-SQL → Line Numbers.

See my blog post about this [here](http://dataartisans.tech/how-to-configure-sql-server-management-studio-for-efficiency/) for more info.

Comment: I tried the way you said... It worked. Thank you very much Chris :)

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it as accepted so it may better help others with the same question in the future.